# Saving and managing attachments in the stock iPhone email app?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, jailbreak, attachments

This has been frustrating me for a long time now. I need to be able to save email attachments (NOT export my attachments to third party apps)

There are so many email apps in the appstore but why is it so difficult for someone to make an app that allows you to save an attachment to the app's filesystem ? Everywhere its Dropbox this, Google Drive that.

EXACTLY like how it works on blackberry like this : http://docs.blackberry.com/ko-kr/smartphone_users/deliverables/11298/Attach_a_file_to_an_email_message_664783_11.jsp

If not an app, Isn't there atleast a jailbreak tweak to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox's email management service app, [Mailbox](http://www.mailboxapp.com/), allows you to open attachments in Dropbox *or* [iFile](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/eu.heinelt.ifile/), which in turn saves the attachment to your `/var/mobile/Documents` folder, but then again, this same thing happens in the stock Mail app (minus the Dropbox integration). What happens is iFile just registers itself as being able to open any file type, so that any application can open its files in iFile. This is how almost every application does it - they simply let iFile do all of the filesystem handling, so they don't have to (it's tricky on iOS; just ask the guy who made [Sandcastle](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=sandcastle2Data)).

If that doesn't fit your needs, however, there is a paid jailbreak tweak called [Attachments+ for Mail](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=attachmentsplusDp) that should do everything you're looking for, and it integrates directly with the stock Mail app (plus, it even looks like it uses Sandcastle), and it's recently been updated for iOS 7.